# Question about Windows userspace memory allocation limits

Tags: c, windows, winapi, virtual-memory

I'm trying to see the maximum address I can allocate memory at in Windows. I'm getting the max address by using `GetSystemInfo`, then trying to allocate one 4KB page. I'm noticing some behavior I haven't seen before, and I'm wondering if someone can explain why it's happening. So first, here's my test code:

```
SYSTEM_INFO info;
GetSystemInfo(&info);

PVOID base = (PUCHAR)info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress - info.dwPageSize;
SIZE_T size = info.dwPageSize;

LPVOID mem = VirtualAlloc(base, size, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

Here are the few things I'm noticing.

1. The size of the allocation is actually larger than the 4KB for one page, it's 64KB. Why?
2. The base address of the allocation is `0x7ffffffe0000`. With a 64KB allocation size, the end address is `7fffffff0000` which is just one byte more than the highest user address. Isn't this going out of bounds?

I am doing this on x64 Windows.

If I could understand why this is happening that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The size of the allocation is actually larger than the 4KB for one page, it's 64KB. Why?

You are not taking `info.dwAllocationGranularity` into account. The page size may be 4K, but the granularity is 64K. Page allocations must be on even multiples of the granularity. So, the base address you are specifying is being rounded down to the next lowest granularity boundary. This is discussed in the [`VirtualAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc) documentation:

> `lpAddress`
>
> The starting address of the region to allocate. If the memory is being reserved, **the specified address is rounded down to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity**. If the memory is already reserved and is being committed, the address is rounded down to the next page boundary. To determine the size of a page and the allocation granularity on the host computer, use the [GetSystemInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsysteminfo) function. If this parameter is NULL, the system determines where to allocate the region.

Also see [Why is address space allocation granularity 64K?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031008-00/?p=42223).

In your case, `info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress` is likely `0x7FFFFFEFFFF` (64K shy of 8TB, which is the max memory supported by Windows 8 and earlier; Windows 8.1 bumps that limit to 128TB).  Subtracting 4K from that is `0x7FFFFFEEFFF`, which then gets rounded down to `0x7FFFFFF0000`, which is an even multiple of 64K.

> The base address of the allocation is 0x7ffffffe0000. With a 64KB allocation size, the end address is 7fffffff0000 which is just one byte more than the highest user address. Isn't this going out of bounds?

`info.lpMaximumApplicationAddress` is acting similar to a 1-past-the-end pointer for an array, or an `end()` iterator for a standard C++ container.  It is a max address you are not supposed to go past, or even dereference.  You can access memory addresses *up to* that max address, but not including it.